# Is it possible to send encrypted base64 string with Alomofire

Tags: json, http, swift3

is it possible to send via Alomofire Session Manager encrypted string  encoded to Base64? All I found was just passing Parameters to request. I'd like to set http request body on my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
let fullBase64String = "data:image/png;base64,\(dataImage))"
```

and then add "fullBase64String" to your parameter

```
let parameter = ["product_img": "\(fullBase64String)"]
headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization" : "Token \(token!)"]
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)
            print(response.result.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I need. I have encrypted JSON, so I cannot use key-value pairs in request.